# Python Eve Framework Authentication not getting applied to selected APIs

Tags: python, rest, authentication, eve

I am writing APIs in Python Eve ,to implement the authentication I followed the documentation written at [Python Eve Authentication](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#basic)

My authentication Class code is as follows :-

```
__author__ = 'sappal'

from eve.auth import BasicAuth

class SampleAuth(BasicAuth):
  def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):

    if method == 'GET' and resource == 'org':
      print "Inside GET Method for Org Resource"

    elif method == 'POST' and resource == 'org':
      print "Inside POST Method for Org Resource "

    elif method == 'GET' and resource == 'people':
      print "Inside GET Method for People Resource"

    elif method == 'POST' and resource == 'people':
      return True
    else:
      return username == 'admin' and password == 'secret'
```

As the code states that I am making POST call on people end-point free of authentication {And that is what I intend to do} ,But When I am making a POST call on the people endpoint [http://127.0.0.1:5000/people] .

I am getting the following Response

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_error"
     {
       "message": "Please provide proper credentials", 
       "code": 401
     }
}
```

My request Payload is :-

```
[
  {
    'firstname': 'Tushar',
    'lastname': 'Sappal',
    'email': 'testemailaddresshurray@gmail.com',
    'phonenumber': 123456789,
    'userid': '',
    'password': 'testtushar'
  }
]
```

I am generating user id on the fly so it is not mandatory value to be passed in the Request Payload .

Please help and guide me ,what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well it is really hard to tell just from that snippet. What is your request? Did you try to print something in POST as well, just to see if the flow is correct? Is the auth class passed to the Eve instance in the first place? Etc.

Comment: hi @NicolaIarocci , my requirement is that I want to make POST call on the people endpoint without any authentication , and authentication mandatory when making POST , GET call on the other endpoints .. PS:- My request   [
    {
      'firstname': 'Tushar',
      'lastname': 'Sappal',
      'email': 'testemailaddresshurray@gmail.com',
      'phonenumber': 123456789,
      'userid': '',
      'password': 'testtushar'
    }
  ]     Yes The Auth Class Instance is passed properly , but the flow is hit only when I provide user name and password otherwise it does not hit ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `public_methods` to `['POST']` for the `people` resource (see [docs](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#global-endpoint-security)). Or you can set `PUBLIC_METHODS` but then you would open up the POST method for all API endpoints.

Comment: I tried setting `public_methods` to `['POST'] ` in `people`  still it is asking for credentials .Schema of people resource.  `people = {
  'item_title': 'person',
  'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
  'cache_expires': 10,
  'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
  'schema': dbtableSchema.schema_people,
  'PUBLIC_METHODS': ['POST']
}`   and  `DOMAIN` is  `DOMAIN = {
  'people': people,
  'org': org,
  'puburl': puburl,
  'address': address,
  'contactnumber': contactnumber,
  'template': template,
  'usersharedcontacts': usersharedcontacts,
  'cardholder': cardholder
}`

Comment: I made a silly mistake in setting  `public_methods` I wrote `PUBLIC_METHODS` instead of `public_methods`..  Thanks @Nicola it worked ...